# Rewind 30 seconds audio and play 2X speed

Tags: iphone, iphone-sdk-3.0, audio, mpmusicplayercontroller

I have a Query regarding playing audio: Can I rewind the audio 30 secs and Play with 2X speed? Is that possible like in Podcasts in iPhone?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you want to speed up sound without making the pitch high and squeaky, then you may need to license a commercial DSP time-pitch stretch library such as Dirac, et.al.  (There may be some open source code to do this in Audacity, but I am unaware of a working iOS port of such).